# query foreign key table for list view in django

Tags: python, django

I am very new to django. I have a django installation and am trying to create a UI in django for a few of the database tables.

In my database there are two tables - Articles and Author. The Articles table has a foreign key to Author table with field name as author_id.

I have managed to create a ListView class that lists articles. The code is like this:

```
from .models import Article

class ArticleListView(ListView):
    template_name = "article.html"
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
        return queryset
```

Then in the view I loop the Article queryset and prints its fields, and this works fine. However I am not sure how to query the corresponding Author table in order to get the author name and details. Can anyone please help me understand how this can be done? I read a lot of documentation/tutorials about this but I am unable to wrap my head around how to do this. Any help is very much appreciated.

Please note: The Article model was written by earlier django programmer.

Comment: You can call the the `.author` attribute to obtain the author, and render it in the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define a `ForeignKey` with name `column` to another model, then Django will construct a database column with the name `column_id` to obtain the primary key of the related object. But you can use `.column` to obtain the related object (so not the `id`, but the corresponding object of that `id`).

You can thus change the template, for example to:

```
<h1>Articles</h1>
<ul>
{% for article in object_list %}
    <li>{{ article.pub_date|date }} - {{ article.headline }}
         - {{article.author.name}}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No articles yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

(given of course an `author` has a `name` field).

Since you here will fetch *all* the author objects, it is usually more efficient to do a `prefetch_related(..)` on the queryset in that case:

```
class ArticleListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'article.html'
    paginate_by = 25

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Article.objects..prefetch_related(
            'author'
        ).order_by('-created_at')
```

You can thus call `.author` on any `Article` *instance* to obtain the `Author` object that relates to it (and for instance fetch properties of that author, modify the author, etc.).

Comment: Do you have any documentation link about this so that I can read what foreign key query options are there? There are other pages/areas where I need to get many foreign key results...

Comment: @UndefinedVariable: I think the documentation on `ForeignKey` is probably a good start: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey Django has a quite good documentation to be honest.

Comment: Thank you once more, I truly appreciate your help.